# How can I get the salt of the hash algorithm that ASP.NET membership uses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, hash, asp.net-membership

What I found is that the default hashing is `SHA1` but they also salt it, you can take a look below:

```
public string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
    byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

I need the salt.. so I guess it gets the salt from some place, some file like the web config or it calculates the salt.. I dont know

How can I get the `salt` of the hash algorithm that `ASP.NET membership` uses?

Comment: likely its based on the machine key - what asp.net membership provider are you using?

Comment: I took a look to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and membership should be in the DLL System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll I'm using the version 4.0.0.0 of this DLL because I'm are using .NET 4.5 and ASP.Net MVC 4 @DanielA.White

Comment: that guy is abstract - specifically which one?

Comment: No @DanielA.White. Salt is unique and random for every password.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the corresponding salt value for each password from the aspnet_Membership table.

From the Membership Providers documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx):

> The salt is a random 128-bit value generated by the .NET Framework's RNGCryptoServiceProvider class. Each password/password answer pair is salted with this unique value, and the salt is stored in the aspnet_Membership table's PasswordSalt field. The result of hashing the password and the salt is stored in the Password field.